# How to develop a ReST api which is secured?

Tags: rest

Here is what I'm looking for, I want to develop a *ReST api* (with any of GET, POST methods) which is secured. In secured I mean, generally in order to access a ReST api we use "http://host:port/resource", but here I want my URL looking like "https://host:port/resource". Please correct me if my approach is wrong.

Comment: Configure your web server to use SSL?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion , could you please describe how to configure web server (tomcat) to use SSL, a live example is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Configure SSL on your server. You can use one-way SSL or two-way SSL depending on your usecase. You may need to configure certificates though!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion , could you please describe how to configure web server (tomcat) to use SSL, a live example is very helpful

Comment: You could probably take a look at the following - http://java.dzone.com/articles/setting-ssl-tomcat-5-minutes